# Customize the behavior of Magento2 grouped products

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

I'd like to use grouped products, to keep a series of items in one place. But I also would like the ability to select different items within the group, changing the product image and description plus attributes as the user wishes. Each one of the elements would have its own data to load, within the same grouped page. I know this is doable with custom work - I have here a link to a magento 1 site that did it: http://www.feldheim.com/kids-speak-series.html - They show the grouped products in a dropdown.

I'd like pointers into how to implement a similar idea in a magento2 website.

Alternatively, maybe I should be creating a customized product type and work from there, but how?